# Compile error in Java object conversion

Tags: java, object, instance, object-type

I have a problem and I'm wondering if anyone knows why:

```
if(n.getInfo() instanceof Token){
   //Token abc = n.getInfo();
  System.out.print("ouch!");
}
```

when it runs, it prints out `ouch!`.

However, when I uncomment the line

```
  Token abc = n.getInfo();
```

it gives a compile error:

```
error: incompatible types: Object cannot be converted to Token
        Token abc = n.getInfo();
```

I don't understand, as it is an instance of `Token`, so how it cannot be converted to `Token`?

Thanks.

Comment: Just a note; when you're using `instanceof` it probably means you're doing something not very OO style. I'd say it's a telltale sign to have a good look at your code.

Answer (score 6):

You've tested that it's an instance, you need to add a cast

```
Token abc = (Token) n.getInfo();
```

Comment: You might want to mention that the giveaway here is the return type delcared for getInfo()...

Answer (score 2):

`n.getInfo()` could be declared to return, for example, `Object`

Clearly if this was the case, it would be the same as saying:

```
Object blah = n.getInfo();
Token abc = blah;
```

And that wouldn't work.  To fix it, you would need:

```
Token abc = (Token)blah;
```